# Cant handle a response error on django-rest-framework

Tags: error-handling, django-rest-framework, response

I am trying to return 400 bad requets response when a user with a company created tries to create another one on my API

I tried with a Response but it does not work, it seems that it does not enter on the if

```
class CompanyViewSet(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return UserCompany.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user.id)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        queryset = UserCompany.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user.id)

        if queryset.exists():
            content = {'API response error:': 'Can have only a one company for every user'}
            return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

When I create a company in user that already has one returns state 200 but don't create it, I expected it to return state 400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `perform_create` only save `serializer` . If you want control status response, you should override `create`. Try like this:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = UserCompany.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user.id)
    if queryset.exists():
        content = {'API response error:': 'Can have only a one company for every user'}
        return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_create(serializer)
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```